# Working on two frames on samsung tab with appium

Tags: android, appium

I am using appium to automate android application. I have the requirement to check SD card option on device but when I am launching settings on samsung tab it has two vertical frames and on scrolling using appium it scrolls default frame but i need to scroll the other right frame . How this can be achieved using appium.

Comment: could you please share a screenshot of the device and elaborate what you want to scroll in that? inspector screenshot would be great as well

Comment: How are you launching Settings apps and how the scroll bars look like ?

Comment: I am launching settings bar with intent through adb and the settings bar is divided into two vertical sections separated by Vertical scroll bar and whenever the scroll is called the left Vertical column is scrolled and I want the right one to be scrolled.